# Site map for assets

Tags: plugin-sitemap

I'm using the sitemap.xml plugin to generate a site map. This works for entries, but doesn't seem to allow the indexing of assets (PDFs in particular). Is there a way to create a site map of an asset directory dynamically, or through a dedicated entry that will create one?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create a dynamic sitemap with a Craft assets query, using any of the search parameters. https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/assets.html#search